# Shortest way to specify a return value expectation for a specific argument in Mockery

Tags: phpunit, mockery

I want to create a `Mock` with a method that should return `true` for a specific argument, and `false` for any other argument.

I can achieve this with:

```
$this->myMock = Mockery::mock(MyClass::class);
$this->myMock->shouldReceive('myMethod')->with('my-argument')->andReturn(true);
$this->myMock->shouldReceive('myMethod')->andReturn(false);
```

But I was wondering if there's any shorter way to specify this, as I have to do this for *many* mocks, and looks like a lot of code for this simple purpose (note my properties/classes/methods/arguments names are quite longer than this example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered I can use:

```
$this->myMock = Mockery::mock(MyClass::class);
$this->myMock->shouldReceive('myMethod')->passthru();
```

This will defer the calls to `myMethod()` to the real object, which will return `true` or `false` depending on the argument - this obviously doesn't do the same thing the code in the question does, but it does work in my scenario and it's quite shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mockery's `andReturnUsing`-method. It takes a closure to calculate the return value by evaluating the provided argument. Should work like:

```
$this->mock
    ->shouldReceive('myMethod')
    ->andReturnUsing(function ($argument) {
        if ($argument) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });
```